# .length(), strlen(n), and sizeof(n) does not work with string and cstring

Tags: c++, string, c-strings, sizeof, strlen

I'm trying to write code that outputs the length of a string.

```
int main(){
    string s1, s2;
    scanf("%s %s", &s1, &s2); //Doesn't work.
    cin >> s1, s2; //Works, I inputed abcd abc
    int s2len = s2.length(); //Incorrect, outputted 0 instead of 3
    int s2len = sizeof(s2.c_str()); //Incorrect, outputted 8
    int s2len = strlen(s2.c_str()); //Incorrect, outputted 0
}
```

Can someone tell me why line 3 doesn't work while 4 does?

Also, I have an understanding that I declared `s1` and `s2` as `string`s which can only interact with `.length()`, which didn't work. Then I tried converting the strings into cstrings with `.c_str()`, which means I must use `sizeof()` or `strlen()`. But that still didn't work.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing out?

Comment: `cin >> s1, s2;` is basically `cin >> s1; s2;` and doesn't do what you think. Try `cin >> s1 >> s2;` instead.

Comment: `scanf` is a C feature and is not aware of class types. It can't work with `std::string` which is a C++ class type. A "string" in C terms is just an array of `char` that is null terminated.

Comment: C++ is highly complex language, you can't learn it by guessing the syntax and asking random questions on the internet. Get [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn from.

Comment: Note: always test the stream after an IO transaction (`if (cin >> s1 >> s2) { safe to use s1 and s2} else {failed to get s1 or s2. do not use them! }`) so you can be sure that the transaction succeeded. If you don't look for and handle errors the time you saved writing less code will be eaten up hundreds or thousands of times over debugging.

Comment: Is that a `std::string`?

Comment: *"`//Works, I inputed abcd abc`"* -- This demonstrates how focusing on the desired behavior can be detrimental to testing. You entered input that you expected would be accepted. When it was accepted, you called it "works". However, did you consider undesired behavior? What happens if you enter too much or too little, as in `abcd abc ab` or only `abcd`? What what you have expected to happen? The program accepting too little input would have become a clue that the code does not truly work as intended.

Comment: __Debugging tip:__ When the length of a string is not what you expect, it is often a good idea to look at the string itself, as in `std::cout << s2 << "\n";`. If this comes up empty, add some delimiters in case there are invisible characters (like spaces), as in `std::cout << "|" << s2 << "|\n";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are making several invalid assumptions about how things work in C++.    It is your expectations that are incorrect.

In explaining, I'm also going to have to make assumptions (to fill in relevant information that you omitted).   I assume that the code you have shown is incomplete, and it is actually preceded by (something like);

```
  #include <string>           //  for the std::string type
  #include <iostream>         //   iostreams, including std::cin
  #include <cstdio>           //   C I/O functions like std::scanf()
  
  using namespace std;        //  so you can avoid std:: prefix in your code
```

When I quote part of your code, I leave the comments intact, and then explain why your code (and therefore your comments) are incorrect.

The first line that doesn't work in your code

```
   scanf("%s %s", &s1, &s2); //Doesn't work.
```

is wrong because the `%s` format tells `scanf()` to ASSUME that the corresponding arguments are pointers to `char` (i.e. a `char *`) and that each of those pointers points at an array of `char` long enough to hold input received.

In reality, `s1` and `s2` are both C++ objects (formally, instances of `std::string`, which is another name for `std::basic_string<char>`).   Neither is an array of `char`.

Since `scanf()` is being told by the `%s` format to ASSUME the two arguments passed are arrays of `char`,  and the arguments being passed are not,  the call of `scanf()` has undefined behaviour.

Some compilers will issue a warning on the `scanf()` call due to the type mismatch.   But compilers are not required to do that (that is the part of the nature of undefined behaviour - no diagnostics are required).

In the following, I'll assume the call `scanf()` did nothing (i.e. it didn't change `s1` or `s2` or anything else at all).   In reality, depending on what you input, it could overwrite arbitrary memory.

The next assumption you make is that

```
cin >> s1, s2; //Works, I inputed abcd abc
```

actually receives input into objects `s1` and `s2`.   It doesn't.   In reality, the expression `cin >> s1, s2` is equivalent to `(cin >> s1), s2`.    This actually has two distinct sub-expressions, `(cin >> s1)` and `s2` separated by the comma operator.  The comma operator causes `(cin >> s1)` to be evaluated (which has an effect of reading data from `std::cin` to `s1`),  then evaluates `s2` (without modifying it).

(There's more to the comma operator than that, but for purposes of explaining here, the above is enough).

Because of that, if you entered `abcd abc` to that statement, then the result will be that `s1` will be a `std::string` containing `"abcd"`, `s2` will be unmodified, and the trailing data `abc` will be unread (if your code was to read from `std::cin` later, that data is available to be read then).

If you want to read `abcd` to `s1` and `abc` to `s2`, one option is `cin >> s1 >> s2`.

Now we get to

```
 int s2len = s2.length(); //Incorrect, outputted 0 instead of 3
```

Because of that, `s2.length()` will give a result of zero.   `s2` was created as an empty string (with length zero) and is never modified.

Next we get to

```
int s2len = sizeof(s2.c_str()); //Incorrect, outputted 8
```

You seem to be assuming this should produce information based upon the user input.   Actually, what happens is that the return type of `s2.c_str()` is a `const char *`, and `sizeof(char *)` (for your compiler) gives a size of `8`  (indicating you are using a 64-bit compiler).   Since `sizeof` is a compile-time operator, it does not evaluate the size of user input.

Technically `sizeof(char *)` is implementation-defined.   This means that different compilers can give different results.   For example, a 32-bit compiler would often evaluate `sizeof(char *)` as `4`.   But that value still has no relationship whatsoever to the data you input to your program.

Next we get to

```
int s2len = strlen(s2.c_str()); //Incorrect, outputted 0
```

Now, since `s2` is an empty string (discussed above), `s2.c_str()` gives a pointer to the first element of an array (managed internally by `std::string`) that has a first character `'\0'`.    `strlen()` counts the number of non-zero characters preceding that `'\0'`, then gives a result of zero.

I suggest you find a good textbook on C++, rather than guessing about things like this.  Because your guesswork has been badly wrong.